# Disable automatic resizing of UITableViewCell on reorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios9

I am just testing the new reorder feature of the `UICollectionView` with 2 different sized `UICollectionViewCell`.

When i am dragging a smaller `UICollectionViewCell` over a larger one to replace it, the smaller one is resizing so it fits the larger one.

Anyone got an idea how i can disable/workaround that?

Comment: http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/ here is a great tutorial it could be a good starting point for you. Without code and more detail it's really hard to tell anything

Comment: @Istvan Thank you! It's written in Swift but i think i can adapt it to objc

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell anything without a code, but probably [this](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/) is a good start for you.